# sql replication from sql2000 to sql2008 across domains

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000, replication

I am trying to re-establish replication between a legacy SQL2000 server running on Windows 2003 in domain A and a SQL 2008 server running on Windows 2008 in domain B. The publisher is the SQL2000 server and the subscriber is the SQL2008 server. This was previously configured and working, but was accidentally deleted. When I try to establish the replication I get a synchronization error due to permissions. I suspect it has to do with not having a user with access to both domains but do not know how to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Web Synchronization. It's a bit tricky to set up but you won't have to worry about cross domain security issues.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151763.aspx